# Does 'I'm pregnant with nobody' have a contradiction?

Tags: contractions

Does 'I'm pregnant with nobody' make sense? I try to express I have no baby growing in the uterus.

Comment: No, it does not make sense. I doubt it would make sense in any language.

Comment: A person (or, figuratively, a situation) is pregnant with _something_. If you are "not pregnant" you can simply say or write that.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A I thought it's possible in English... It's impossible in my language too.

Comment: I daresay you could say, sadly, that you thought you were going to have a baby but now you have found out you are pregnant with nothing, and it would be understood. We can use postive + negative expressions for emphasis, e.g. I though Joe was going to help me, but he has done a lot of nothing. It is unusual, though, and would not be used simply to indicate non-pregnancy.

Comment: As @Michael Harvey noted, without a very specific context, the sentence alone is nonsense. To express the idea that you are not pregnant, say "I'm not pregnant” or “I'm not expecting a baby”

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Yes, I don't mean what he means, I decided to accept it's a non-sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity, "pregnant *with*..." usually refers to the unborn baby. If referring to the other parent, we say "pregnant *by*...".

Assuming you understand this, "I'm pregnant with nobody" isn't good grammar, strictly speaking. You would simply say "**I'm not pregnant**".

However, there can be contexts in which we may use that kind of expression either for humorous effect or to conform with other responses.

For example:

> Question: "Who are you going to the party with?"
> Person 1: "I'm going with John"
> Person 2: "I'm going with Jane"
> Person 3: "I'm going with nobody".

So there might be a convoluted context in which you might say "I'm pregnant with nobody", but as a general rule, no - it isn't good grammar.

Comment: The difference is that it is possible to go to a party without a partner, but it is not possible to be pregnant without a baby